# Using variables in Bash boolean expressions

Tags: bash

Can someone explain how to perform Boolean operations and store them in variables in Bash?

I tried:

```
A=true
B=false
C=!$A
D=$A && $B
echo $C
echo $D
```

I also tried without dollars, with [], with {}, ()... How can one do such a simple operation in bash?

result in console are:

```
!true
true
```

It seems they are always treated as strings.

Comment: P.S. more or less 1st time I use bash ...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, bash does not support boolean variables in a proper meaning. There is no "true" and "false" constants as in programming languages. Instead, `/bin/true` and `/bin/false` are two executables that don't do anything except return exit status 0 or 1. Contrary to common logic, exit status 0 is a synonim for "true" and 1 is a synonim for "false". The closest you can get to evaluating boolean expressions is either

- `[[ expr ]]` which returns a exit status 0 or 1 depending on evaluating `expr`
- `&&` and `||` (these are conditionals depending on last command's exit status)
- `[` which is actually an executable with a silly name (not part of bash) that supports some basic expressions
- `if...elif..else..fi` which you can use to your advantage to manipulate variables within the workflow

Comment: It's less of a contradiction if you think of `0` as *success* and non-zero as *failure*, rather than logical truth. `[` is indeed a silly name; it's "real" name is `test`. (`bash` does additionally implement `[`/`test` internally for performance reasons, though.)

Answer (score 4):

You deduced right, `bash` variables by default contain strings, and its values are treated as strings.

You can use the `declare` built-in command to explicitly say they store integers (`declare -i myintvar`), or indexed arrays (`declare -a myarr`), or associative arrays (`declare -A mymap`), etc., *but not booleans*.

The closest you can get to booleans is to use integer values `0` and `1` and evaluate expressions as arithmetic expressions with the `(( expr ))` command (`bash`-specific), or with [arithmetic expansion `$(( expr ))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) (POSIX-compatible). Those commands evaluate `expr` according to rules of [shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic).

For example:

```
A=1
B=0
(( C = \!A ))       # logical negation  ==>  C = 0
(( D = A && B ))    # logical AND       ==>  D = 0
E=$(( A ^ B ))      # bitwise XOR       ==>  E = 1
```

In `bash`, you can also use `declare -i` and `let`:

```
declare -i E='A||B'    # equivalent to: E=$((A||B)), or ((E=A||B))
let C='!A'             # equivalent to: C=$((\!A)), or ((C=\!A))
```

which are a longer way of saying `((..))` or `$((..))`. They both force arithmetic evaluation of the expressions given.

Note that `!` has a special meaning in most shells (including `bash`), it causes history expansion. To prevent it, we must escape it with a backslash, or quote it.

Comment: I would avoid the integer attribute; it's doesn't really provide any value. Your `declare` command doesn't do what you think; `||` is treated as the normal shell operator, so `B` is only executed if `declare -i E=A` fails. You need to quote the value: `declare -i E="A||B"` to have the intended effect of simulating `E=$((A||B))`.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the quotes there. Note that `declare -i` evaluates the expr as arithmetic.

Comment: So does `E=$((A || B))`, which is more explicit as well as being standard.

Comment: @chepner, I've updated my answer a little bit, hope the bash/posix difference is clearer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
t=true
f=false

# if $t; then echo Hi; fi
Hi
# if $f; then echo Hi; fi
# if ! $f; then echo Hi; fi
Hi
# if ! ($t && $t); then echo Hi; fi
# if  ($t && $t); then echo Hi; fi
Hi
```